# How to access video file in website?(ex youtube mp3 converter)

Tags: web-scraping

I've developed the program which predict cabbage price that depend on weather.
So i want to parse the weather data from The Meteorological Administration website. But i already knew that if i has the different domain, i can't access the site that has other domain. 
But a number of people has used youtube-mp3-converter.
So i want to know how they(youtube converter sites) can access the other domain.

- By any chance, did they access server? if it's right,  To parse the other site elements, what i should study first? (i already knew ajax.)

Comment: You want to scrape websites for their data?

Comment: yeah i just want to weather table data.

Comment: But  i need the weather data in real time. Because the weather always change thus cabbage price will change.

Comment: Did you check if they provide any API? Scraping should always be the last resort because it's likely to turn into an maintenance nightmare if the source page layout changes. Also keep in mind that scraping may violate their Terms of Service.

Comment: Oh I see, so it is a homework problem...
Real world application doesn't fluctuate that much in pricing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great news! As a weather service, they have an API you can use. No scraping or other weird parsing needed. Here is a link for you to read more about it: http://data.cma.cn/en/?r=article/getLeft/id/343/keyIndex/30

It looks like you'll have to register an account to get access to their data.